# An inconsistency of the definition of the simple components of a semisimple ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semi-simple-rings

The definition of the simple components of a semisimple ring which I learned is as follow (see Rotman's *Advanced Modern Algebra*):

> Let $R$ be a left semisimple ring,
>   and let $$R=L_1\oplus \cdots \oplus L_n,$$
>   where the $L_p$ are minimal left ideals.
>   Reindex the summands so that no two of the first $r$ ideals $L_1, ..., L_r$ are isomorphic,
>   while every $L_p$ in the given decomposition is isomorphic to some $L_i$ for $1\leq i\leq r$.
>   The left ideals
>   $$B_i=\bigoplus_{L_p\cong L_i}L_p$$
>   are called the simple components of $R$ relative to the decomposition $R=\bigoplus_p L_p$.

Now, suppose that $R=M_2(\Bbb{C})\times M_2(\Bbb{C})$.
Let $L_1=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\b&0\end{pmatrix}\mid a, b\in \Bbb{C}\right\}$
and $L_2=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}0&c\\0&d\end{pmatrix}\mid c, d\in \Bbb{C}\right\}$.
$L_1$ and $L_2$ are both minimal left left ideals in $R$.
According to this definition, 
there is only one simple component of $R$, 
which is $B=L_1\oplus L_2\oplus L_1\oplus L_2$
because $L_1\cong L_2$ as an $R$-module.
However, according Lam's definition (see *Lectures on Modules and Rings*), 
there are two simple components of $R$.
Are there something I misunderstand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L_1'$ and $L_2'$ denote the "version" of $L_1$ and $L_2$ in the second copy of $M_2(\mathbb C)$.

It is true that $L_1\cong L_2\cong L_1'\cong L_2'$ as $M_2(\mathbb C)$ modules, and it is also true that $L_1\cong L_2$ and $L_1'\cong L_2'$ as $R$ modules.

But $L_1\ncong L_1'$ as $R$ modules!

$L_1$ is annihilated by $\{0\}\times M_2(\mathbb C)$ but not by $M_2(\mathbb C)\times\{0\}$, and $L_1'$ is annihilated by $M_2(\mathbb C)\times\{0\}$ but not by $\{0\}\times M_2(\mathbb C)$.

So, you still get two components using the definition in question.

Comment: Ah! I see. Thanks.